# Angular route http get url parameters

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am using Jhipster , angular 4.2.6

I use external module, When it ends process, it redirect url as follows
http://aaa.com/order-status?aaa={value}&bbb={value}
I cannot change this format.

I should link to the url and get this parameters(aaa, bbb) to processing the logic
How can I get this parameters?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKUwy.png)

I do wanna know is How to set route.ts to link http://aaa.com/order-status?aaa={value}&bbb={value} as linked above image

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query Param

Your url: http://aaa.com/order-status?aaa={value}&bbb={value}

Your component:

```
aaa: string;
bbb: string;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.aaa = params.aaa;
            this.bbb = params.bbb;
        });
    }
```

For more info: https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Comment: Thanks. It solved! I just use Params not queryParams